# JScroll with Wookmark not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [jQuery Woodmark Plugin](http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin)
to autocenter and fit list items to the browser window. I'm trying to use [jQuery JScroll Plugin](http://jscroll.com/)
to allow infinite scrolling, but the Woodmark breaks when I implement it.

I'm using Laravel, so this is my blade view

```
<ul class="list-grid">
    <div class="scroller">
        @foreach($activities as $activity)
            <li>
                @include('php_includes.activities.activity', ['route' => 'activity-global','user_id' => null])
            </li>
        @endforeach 
        {{ $activities->links() }}
    </div>
</ul>
```

My JS that I'm using in my footer to make the Woodmark work is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($){
  $(function() {
    var $handler = $('.list-grid li');

    $handler.wookmark({
        // Prepare layout options.
         align: 'center',
         autoResize: true,
         comparator: null,
         container: $('html'),
         direction: undefined,
         ignoreInactiveItems: true,
         itemWidth: 560,
         fillEmptySpace: false,
         flexibleWidth: true,
         offset: 8,
         onLayoutChanged: undefined,
         outerOffset: 0,
         possibleFilters: [],
         resizeDelay: 50,
         verticalOffset: undefined
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

This all works great, but when I try to add the JScroll, the appended items (?page=2) overlap the original items (?page=1) and the Woodmark for the ?page=2 items breaks.

My JS for the JScroll is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//hides the default paginator
    $('ul.pagination:visible:first').hide();

    $('div.scroller').jscroll({
        autoTrigger: true,
        nextSelector: '.pagination li.active + li a',
        contentSelector: 'div.scroller',
        animate: true,
        loadingHtml: '<div class="page-loading"><i class="uk-icon-spin uk-icon-spinner"></i></div>',
        callback: function() {

            //again hide the paginator from view
            $('ul.pagination:visible:first').hide();

        }
    });
});
```

I'm very new to jQuery/JavaScript. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair Sorry I thought the actual plugin was called 'jQuery JScroll'